# Vue2 eslint parsing error - eslint config with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, eslintrc

I am using Vue 2.6.11 with typescript 4.5.2 and i am getting eslint parsing errors which i cant resolve. Tried different eslint configs and updating @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and typescript-eslint/parser with no success.

I hope someone can tell me how to properly set up the project in order to use typescript.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
```

eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/standard',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

getting parsing in the debounce-function (marked it in the code as comment):

> ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?

```
export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    SearchSpecification
  },
  data () {
    return {
      searchFieldInput: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    searchFieldInput: function (value) {
      this.debounce(() => console.log(value), 500)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    debounce: function <T extends Function>(cb: T, wait = 20) {
      let h = 0;
      console.log(cb);
      let callable = (...args: any) => {
        console.log(...args);
        clearTimeout(h);
        h = setTimeout(() => cb(...args), wait);
      };
      return <T>(<any>callable);
    } // <-- parsing error here before the bracket
  }
})
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my eslintrc or maybe even something else or how i can set up Vue with typescript correctly to not get those or other parsing errors?